# What's cosmic VCF?

Tags: bioinformatics

The popular MuTect variant tool:

> http://archive.broadinstitute.org/cancer/cga/mutect_run

has the following VCF option:

> --cosmic < comic.vcf >

**Q:** What is this cosmic VCF file? What's the purpose of the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**VCF**](http://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/vcf4.0/) is an abbreviation for Variant Call Format. It is a file format for SNPs.

[**COSMIC**](http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/) stands for Catalogue Of Somatic Mutations In Cancer. It is a database.

Have a look at the links for more information.

A COSMIC VCF is likely just a file in VCF format file containing data coming from the COSMIC data base.

Answer (score 3):

Without looking at any mutect docs and how it might use this, the COSMIC VCF would refer to a VCF from the cosmic database http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/